# TS2322: Type 'Atrribute' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'. Toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I tried first isToggle and onToggle to be a boolean type, but it still warning about the types after the change you can see below.

This is error of checked:
Type 'Atrribute' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

This is error of onChange :
Type 'Atrribute' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler'.
Type 'Atrribute' provides no match for the signature '(event: ChangeEvent): void'.

```
import React, {ChangeEventHandler} from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import './SwitchToggle.css';

interface Atrribute{
    rounded:boolean;
    isToggled:boolean|undefined;
    onToggle:ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}

const SwitchToggle =(rounded:Atrribute ,isToggled:Atrribute,onToggle:Atrribute)=>{

    const sliderCX = classNames("slider",{
        "rounded":rounded
    })

    return(
        <label className={"switch"}>
            <input type={"checkbox"} checked={isToggled} onChange={onToggle}/>
            <span className={sliderCX}/>
        </label>
    )
}

export default SwitchToggle;
```

I also use this code in main and its work fine

```
const [isToggled,setTisToggled] = useState(false);

<SwitchToggle isToggled{...SwitchToggle.prototype.isToggled} onToggle={()=>setTisToggled(!SwitchToggle.prototype.isToggle)}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write like this...

```
const SwitchToggle =({ rounded, isToggled ,onToggle }:Atrribute)=>{
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how you destructure function arguments:

```
const SwitchToggle = (rounded:Atrribute ,isToggled:Atrribute,onToggle:Atrribute) => {...}
```

What you're telling TypeScript here is that this function will receive three arguments, each of them being of type `Atrribute`.  But instead this function will receive *one* argument, of type `Atrribute`, from which you want to destructure three properties.

To destructure an object, use the `{}` destructuring syntax:

```
const SwitchToggle = ({ rounded, isToggled, onToggle } : Atrribute) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your props declaration is wrong. You can't write your props this way :

`const SwitchToggle =(rounded:Atrribute ,isToggled:Atrribute,onToggle:Atrribute) => {...}`

`Atrribute` is the type of your entire `props` object, so you should write it this way :

`const SwitchToggle =(props:Atrribute) => {...}`

Or, if you want to destructure your object, then it'll be something like :

`const SwitchToggle =({rounded, isToggled, onToggle}:Atrribute) => {...}`

P.S. : You misswrote `Atrribute`.